# Processing HTML with UIMA

Tags: html-parsing, uima

I am trying to get my head around the UIMA architecture.

I would like to create a pipeline that starts with HTML markup. I need to strip this to plain text, so it can be processed by different annotators, like POS, chunking, entity detection, etc. However I would also like to keep track of which regions correspond to the original html tags, like links, paragraphs, em, etc. Basically I would like a final annotator that takes advantage of structural annotations (from html) and semantic annotations (from the other components), all at once.

So, I can imagine starting off with a component that strips the html markup and adds annotations to keep track of the tags I am interested in. Does such a component exist already? It seems like something a lot of people would want.

If I do have to create it from scratch, what kind of component is it? It's not just a straight annotator, because it needs to change the SOFA: it needs to replace the markup with plain text.

Or should I have it create a new view of the document, so we maintain a markup view and a plain text view of the document? This seems weird, considering I will never care about the markup view again. Also, how would I make sure the other annotators (which I won't be coding myself) operate on the plain text view of the document rather than the markup view?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of the markup, some people use Apache Tika, and some people use Boilerpipe.

[Here is a blog post](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2011/08/uima-concept-mapping-interface-to.html) from someone who wanted to use Boilerpipe in UIMA but ran into a snag because he wanted to preserve offsets back to the HTML.

[Here is the UIMA annotator that calls tika.](http://uima.apache.org/sandbox.html#tika.annotator)

Answer (score 1):

[UIMA Ruta](http://uima.apache.org/ruta.html) provides some analysis engines for this task. The [HtmlAnnotator](http://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.ae.html) creates annotations in the html text for the different tags. The [HtmlConverter](http://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.ae.htmlconverter) is able to create a new view that contains only the text of the html, but with the corresponding annotations for the tags. There are some configuration parameters for handling linebreaks and so on. For further processing without sofa mappings in a pipeline, there is the ViewWriter that is able copy the new plain text view to the _initalView of a new file.

DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta